# UISlider and REAL Time

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, nstimer, uislider

I'm trying to use a UISlider to act as a Time limit.  Problem is that the values go to .99 before flipping to 1.

My code so far is

```
int _min = (int)mySlider.value;
NSLog(@"Slider Int Minutes %i",_min);

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f",mySlider.value];
int stringLength = [str length];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, stringLength);
NSString *newStr = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@":" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:range];

NSLog(@"Old String: '%@' --> New String: '%@'", str, newStr);
```

So the slider works, but I would like once the decimal place hits .60 it increases by 1 and resets the decimals to .00

Screenshot Attached.

Thanks,
Jason Jardim

Comment: NSString's `length` method returns `NSUInteger`, not `int`. In this case, it's harmless, but you should get into the habit of using the correct type before you encounter a case where it isn't harmless.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not fussing with the slider - let it measure decimal minutes, then convert to MM:SS for display.

For example: if the slider would display 1:30, the actual output of `mySlider.value` is 1.5.